# Conjugation with real elements

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Suppose I have an expression, such as

```
A = 5 t^2 + 3 t + 4;
```

I want to define the variable t to be real, therefore I can write

```
A = Refine[A, {Element[t, Reals], t > 0}];
```

now if I take the complex conjugate of this expression:

```
Conjugate[A]
```

I get the result:

```
4 + 3 Conjugate[t] + 5 Conjugate[t]^2
```

What am I doing wrong? I want Mathematica to recognize that the variable t is real, so that `Conjugate[A]` will return

```
4 + 3t + 5t^2
```

Comment: When you evaluated `Conjugate[A]`, the assumptions you explicitly specified in `Refine[A, {Element[t, Reals], t > 0}]` **are not remembered**, so `t` is again treated as complex. So you need to somehow explicitly specify your assumptions again before evaluating `Conjugate[A]`, as thorimur demonstrates in the answer given.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome to MMA SE! The assumption `Element[t, Reals]` is only used inside `Refine`, and so in a sense is not "known to" any evaluations outside of that expression. `Refine` doesn't change the nature of `A`; it merely spits out an expression produced from its argument evaluated under the provided assumptions. The assumptions don't "remain attached" to the symbol `A`.

You have a couple different ways to proceed:

0. Simply `Refine[Conjugate[A], {Element[t, Reals], t > 0}]`!

In the following I'll mention other general strategies for applying assumptions, using `Simplify` as a way of applying them, but everything applies equally well to using `Refine` and other similar expressions in place of `Simplify`. (Note, though, that to use `Simplify` with assumptions, though, you need to provide them as an option, e.g.  `Simplify[Conjugate[A], Assumptions -> {Element[t, Reals]}]`)

1. Set global assumptions via `$Assumptions`, e.g.

```
$Assumptions = {Element[t, Reals]}
```

Then e.g. `Simplify[Conjugate[t]]` will return `t` and `Simplify[Conjugate[A]]` will return `A`. Likewise for `Refine[Conjugate[A]]`. (Note that `Conjugate[t]` will still return `Conjugate[t]`.)

2. Wrap your expressions in `Assuming` and use `Simplify`/`Refine`, e.g.

```
Assuming[{Element[t, Reals]}, Simplify[Conjugate[A]]]
```

This is essentially a local version of the above; it's equivalent to temporarily appending to `$Assumptions`

3. Bypass assumptions and set an [upvalue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) for `t`:

```
t /: Conjugate[t] := t
```

This won't make `t` be assumed to be real in simplifying procedures, in general; it will only replace the actual expression `Conjugate[t]` with `t` when encountered. So, it relies on `Conjugate[t]` being present as-is, and while it does mean you don't have to use `Simplify`/`Refine`, it is rather fragile due to how specific it is.

Let me know if anything here doesn't make sense or could use expanding upon!

Answer (score 4):

Using **ComplexExpand** command:

```
A = 5 t^2 + 3 t + 4;
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[A]]
```

For expressions within radicals, we must use the **Refine** command for the **ComplexExpand** command to work properly. Here is an example:

Without Refine command:

```
 Simplify[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[a - b c]]]]
 (*((a - b c)^2)^(1/4) (Cos[1/2 Arg[a - b c]] - I Sin[1/2 Arg[a - b c]])*)
```

With **Refine** command for $a-bc>0$ or $a-bc<0$

```
 Refine[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[a - b c]]], Assumptions -> a - b c > 0]
 (*Sqrt[a - b c]*)

 Refine[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[a - b c]]], Assumptions -> a - b c < 0]
 (*- I*Sqrt[b c - a]*)
```