# Conjugating real elements

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions, complex

Facing the same problem reported here: [Conjugation with real elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239532/conjugation-with-real-elements,whose) answers are working, I thought of the following solution:

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate[x_] := x /; Element[x, Reals]
Protect[Conjugate];
```

but when I test it:

```
$Assumptions = {Element[y, Reals]};
Conjugate[y]
(* output *)
Conjugate[y]
```

doesn't seem to be doing what I need. If I don't use `$Assumptions`, then:

```
Refine[y, y \[Element] Reals];
Conjugate[y]
Simplify[Conjugate[y]]
(* output *)
Conjugate[y]
Conjugate[y]
```

Can someone please explain why my "solution" is not working?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. Note that Mathematica doesn't automatically perform _all_ simplifications. For example, evaluating `x/x` will immediately simplify to `1`, but for some more complicated expression, you _need_ to use `Simplify` (or `FullSimplify`). Your "solution" does not work because the assumption that $y$ is real is not automatically taken into account, and therefore your custom downvalue (`Conjugate[x_] := x /; Element[x, Reals]`) is not used.

Comment: I am not sure you are using `Refine` correctly. It seems to me like you used it like Assumptions expecting `Refine[y, y \[Element] Reals]`; to imply that `y` will be real throughout the notebook but `Refine` only acts locally on it's first argument by applying the assumptions from the second argument.

Comment: you can try the following

Comment: `Refine[y, y \[Element] Reals] // 
 EchoLabel["Refine[y,y\[Element]Reals]"]; 
Conjugate[y] // EchoLabel["Conjugate[y]"]; 
Refine[Conjugate[y], y \[Element] Reals] // 
 EchoLabel["Refine[Conjugate[y],y\[Element]Reals]"]; 
Conjugate[y] // EchoLabel["Conjugate[y]"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$Assumptions` only affects functions which use the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html). Since [`Conjugate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate.html) takes no options, `$Assumptions` has no effect on it.

```
$Assumptions = y ∈ Reals;

Conjugate[y]

(* Conjugate[y] *)
```

However, [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) uses `Assumptions` and through it, `$Assumptions`

```
Simplify[Conjugate[y]]

(* y *)
```

Alternatively, [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) will assume that all variables are real unless explicitly told otherwise.

```
$Assumptions = True (* clearing $Assumptions *)

ComplexExpand[Conjugate[y]]

(* y *)
```

Comment: Just adding for OP that `Options[Simplify]` shows `Assumptions :> $Assumptions` which might help understand why `$Assumptions = y ∈ Reals; Simplify[Conjugate[y]]` has the same effect as changing the option directly via  `Simplify[Conjugate[y], Assumptions -> y \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: Notice also the `:>`  rather than `->`. Changing `:>` to `->` has the effect that `$Assumptions = True; SetOptions[Simplify, 
 Assumptions -> $Assumptions]; $Assumptions = 
 y \[Element] Reals; Simplify[Conjugate[y]]` outputs  `Conjugate[y]`